# Flutter SetState is not working when in GridView

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

When I tap in a image in the GridView Widget, it's supose to change to the image without the opacity, but it's not working as it should. The list is working well, and I can add and remove images from the list, but the result it's not showed on the screen.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 410,
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      mainAxisExtent: 160,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    ),
                    itemCount: data[0].products!.length,
                    physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            (isSelected.contains(data[0].products![index])
                                ? isSelected.remove(data[0].products![index])
                                : isSelected.add(data[0].products![index]));
                          });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              (isSelected.contains(data[0].products![index])
                                  ? SizedBox(
                                      height: 90,
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                          data[0].products![index].image))
                                  : SizedBox(
                                      height: 90,
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                        data[0].products![index].image,
                                        opacity:
                                            const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(.5),
                                      ),
                                    )),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 8,
                              ),
                              Text(data[0].products![index].name)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: You should really post enough code in your question that someone could copy and paste without errors. For example, removing `data[0]` and replacing them with random names and image URLs. Especially with visual questions like Flutter, it's helpful for people to paste your code into `dartpad.dev` and run it there, and we can't do that if some parts of your code are missing

Comment: Also, you've demonstrated that `setState` _is_ working, it's just the opacity that isn't